# Finding the dimension of a tangent space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set and $\mathbf{y}\in X$.
>
> Assume that  $\mathbf{g}:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is injective so that
>   $\mathbf{g}^{-1}$ is continuous. And suppose $\mathbf{g}$ is
>   differentiable at $\mathbf{y}$.
>
> We say that $\mathbf z$ is tangent to $\mathbf g(X)$ at $\mathbf
>  g(\mathbf y)$ if there exists $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with
>   $\mathbf{z}=D\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{y})\mathbf{u}$, where $D$ denotes the
>   Jacobian matrix. An equivalent condition is that there exist $r>0$ and
>   a path $p:(-r,r)\to X$ such that $p(0)=\mathbf{y}$ and such that $p$
>   is differentiable at $0$ with $(\mathbf{g}\circ p)'(0)=\mathbf{z}$.
>
> Let $\mathbf{G}:X\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be given by
>   $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})=(\mathbf{x},g(\mathbf{x}))$.
>
> We have that $\mathbf{G}(X)=\Gamma_g:=\{(\mathbf{x},g(\mathbf{x}))\ :\
>  \mathbf{x}\in X\}$.
>
> Now set $S=\{\mathbf{z}\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\ :\ \mathbf{z}\ \mbox{is
>  tangent to}\ \Gamma_g\ \mbox{at}\ (\mathbf{y},g(\mathbf{y}))\}.$

I want to show (i) that $S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\ \vdots\\ u_n\\ Dg(\mathbf{y})\mathbf{u}\end{bmatrix} : \mathbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}{u_1\\ \vdots\\ u_n}\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^n,\right\}$ and (ii) that $\dim S=n$.

I have no idea how to proceed, however. I can compute the Jacobian of $\mathbf G$ and then look at the column rank as mentioned below, but I'm unsure of how this gets the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ${\bf G}$ produces an $n$-dimensional graph surface over the base space ${\mathbb R}^n$. Note that $D{\bf G}({\bf y})$ has matrix
$$\left[\matrix{
1\cr
&1\cr
&&1\cr
&&&\ddots\cr
&&&&1\cr
g_{.1}({\bf y})&g_{.2}({\bf y})&g_{.3}({\bf y})&\cdots&g_{.n}({\bf y})\cr}\right]\ .$$
Your  statement (i) is  just a restatement of your first characterization of tangent vectors, resp., of $S$.

The above matrix obviously has $n$ linearly independent rows (as well as $n$ linearly independent columns), hence rank $n$. These $n$ columns, the images  $D{\bf G}({\bf y}).{\bf e}_k$ of the $n$ basis vectors ${\bf e}_k$ of ${\mathbb R}^n$,  span $S$. It follows that ${\rm dim}(S)=n$, as claimed in (ii).

Comment: I understand that $D\mathbf G$ has that matrix, but how does the fact that the column rank is $n$ imply that $\dim S=n$? I don't see the connection. (I'm also a bit rusty on how to find the column rank of a matrix. Here, can we show that the columns are linearly independent?)